# How would I pass a parameter to Oracle stored procedure that would determine the number of parallel slave processes to open

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

In my stored procedure I would like the number of slave processes opened by Oracle to be dynamic but whenever I execute the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_TEST(Text_Sample VARCHAR2, parallelNumber NUMBER) AS
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Text_Sample);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(parallelNumber);
    UPDATE  /*+ parallel(parallelNumber) */  EMPLOYEE SET ID = NULL; 
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/

set serveroutput on;

exec PROCEDURE_TEST('Test', 10);
```

This the query that gets fired (Checked from history)

```
UPDATE /*+ parallel(parallelNumber) */ EMPLOYEE SET ID = NULL
```

So the variable parallelNumber is not getting substituted in the parallel hint.

Is there a way where I can make this variable passed a part of my hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use dynamic SQL to inject a variable degree of parallelism:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_TEST(Text_Sample VARCHAR2, parallelNumber NUMBER) AS
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Text_Sample);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(parallelNumber);
    execute immediate
              'UPDATE /*+ parallel(' || parallelNumber || ') */ EMPLOYEE SET ID = NULL'; 
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

But you wouldn't want to do this in real life. Most of the time the optimizer is better at deciding on the best Degree of Parallelism value than we are.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked! And I will keep that tip in mind. For now need this as a part of an experiment.